# Ajax to node.js express module isn't giving a response

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm using node.js and JQuery to communicate. Whenever I send a post request to my node.js express server, it receives the request but does not seem to give a response.

**Client code:**

```
     $("#submitdetails").click(function(){
  $.post("http://neztorian.xyz:26/",
    {
        name: "Donald Duck",
        city: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });

});
```

**Sever code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
console.log("Running");
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body);

res.send("recieved");

})
app.listen(26);
```

The server receives the post request and logs it to console but the alert message does not appear on the client. Thank you for your help. Sorry if this is a stupid question.

**Edit: Thank you for your answers. Problem was:** `Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://neztorian.xyz:26' is therefore not allowed access.` I've fixed the issue by adding that header to the server.

Comment: What is `#submitdetails` ? Is it part of a form and page is refreshing? If so need to prevent default action in click or submit handler. Also use error handler on the ajax to get more detail

Comment: Check the console in your browser, you will probably see something like  `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://neztorian.xyz:26' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Then read: [why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present) , [no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is not allowed by the browser because the server is not sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Set the header and request are allowed.

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://neztorian.xyz:26'); 
  res.send("recieved");
});
```

Read more here: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)